# Selecting dynamic column in oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Table userdetail

```
Username    Department
user1       dept2
user2       dept3
user3       dept4
```

Table department

```
dept1    dept2    dept4    dept3     amount       region      city
hello    bye      tc       tata      500          pakistan    lahore
```

Now If I select "user1" output should be like that

```
dept2   dept4   dept3   amount   region       city
bye     tc      tata    500      pakistan     lahore
```

Now If I select "user3" output should be like that

```
dept4   amount   region    city
tc      500      pakistan  lahore
```

Answer (score 1):

Your design is not realy relational..
Typically a `DEPARTNEMT` table consist of department id (primary key) and ather attributes.

Also a Query returns always the same number of columns, so it is not possible to return once six columns and four columns for ather value.

Anyway, if the department table has only one row, you may do something like this

```
select u.Username, 
decode(u.Department,'dept2',d.dept2,'dept3',d.dept3, 'dept4',d.dept4) dept,
decode(u.Department,'dept2',d.amount,'dept3',d.amount, 'dept4',d.amount) amount
from userdetail u 
cross join department d 
where u.Username = 'user1'

USERNAME DEPT     AMOUNT
-------- ---- ----------
user1    bye         500
```

Add other columns based on this schema, if required.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.username, b.Department, b.amount, b.region, b.city
from userdetail a inner join  
(
select 'dept1' as Department, dept1 as dept, amount, region, city
from department
union all
select 'dept2' as Department2,dept2 as dept2, amount, region, city
from department
union all
select 'dept3' as Department3,dept3 as dept3, amount, region, city
from department
union all
select 'dept4' as Department4,dept4 as dept4, amount, region, city
from department
) b on (a.department=b.Department)
where a.username= 'user1';
```